# Increase bit rate while converting FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing

I am trying to convert an .mp4 to .mpeg using:

```
ffmpeg -i "01_b.wmv" -an -c:v mpeg1video -b:v 20M "intro.mpeg"
```

My source video is 20MB/s but the converted .mpeg file doesn't ever go that high (usually ends up being around 12MB/s).

Is there something I am missing? I am relatively inexperienced with FFMPEG, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you want to hit a particular bitrate, you use 2-pass encoding. First pass analyzes the video, then the second pass does the actual encoding based on the first-pass data. I'm not familiar with `mpeg1video` encoder but I suspect you can follow [the h264 encoding example](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264#twopass) and see if it applies to your codec choice.

Answer (score 0):

The bit rate is calculated to an average at output versus being a simple duration/file size calculation. 100MB file, 10s = 10Mb/s, even though 40Mb/s could be the two seconds, and the rest is a lower bit rate.